# Is there way to check device model in Apportable SDK?

Tags: apportable

I have to implement some special behaviour for particular device model. So I need to check  device model.

I'm using

```
[UIDevice currentDevice] name];
```

but it's return me something like this

```
Nexus 7 running Apportable
```

I think it's kind of weird result. Any other way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `[[UIDevice currentDevice] nativeModel]`

```
NSLog(@"%@", [[UIDevice currentDevice] nativeModel]);
```

will generate `D/Spin    ( 3956): 2014-04-14 09:44:21.446 Spin[3956:2752] Nexus 7` in logcat output

There is more information about the UIDevice API extensions in `.apportable/SDK/System/UIKit/UIDevice.h`

Apportable typically makes API decisions for iOS ports to be as seamless as possible. If you actually want an Android specific result, a non-iOS API extension is usually created.

Here are some details on the UIDevice.h mappings to the [Android Build API's](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.html):

```
@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSString *nativeSystemName;    -> @"Android" 
@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSString *nativeCPUABI;        -> Build.CPU_ABI
@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSString *nativeModel;         -> Build.MODEL
@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSString *nativeProduct;       -> Build.PRODUCT
@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSString *nativeManufacturer;  -> Build.MANUFACTURER
@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSString *nativeSystemVersion; -> Build.RELEASE
@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSUInteger nativeSDKVersion;   -> Build.SDK_INT
```

Comment: Will it give me same results for 2012 and 2013 Nexus?

Comment: If it nativeModel doesn't give a different string, nativeProduct might. See the updated answer